EventBus @ConsumeEvent and @TestTransaction
I am using @TestTransaction in my QuarkusTest to make sure the DB is left intact after the tests complete.
One issue however is that EventBus listeners are not seeing the changes made in the test ("main") thread... for example:
    @Test
    @TestTransaction
    public void generateTestPayments() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        paymentService.createPayment(xxx);
    }

// PaymentService bean:
   
   public void createPayment(xxx) { 
     createPaymentTx(yyy);
    _bus.publish(BusChannel.payment_created, new PaymentMessage(...));
   }

   @Transactional
   void createPaymentTx(yyy) { batisMapper.insertPayment(yyy); }

// PaymentStewart bean:
    @ConsumeEvent(value = BusChannel.payment_created)
    @Blocking
    @ActivateRequestContext
    public void handleOrderStatusUpdate(PaymentStatusMessage msg)
    {
       batisMapper.getPayment(msg.getPaymentId()) ---> not found
    }


My understanding is that since the entire test runs inside a test transaction the insert is never committed, and thus is not seen by other threads.
My current workaround is to disable problematic event consumers in tests, and to invoke them "manually" from the test methods... which is tedious and error-prone.
Is there a better approach?
Thanks!
Franck
